# Thread-safe classes explanation in Java

Tags: java, thread-safety

Let's consider this situation:

```
public class A {
    private Vector<B> v  = new Vector<B>();
}

public class B {
    private HashSet<C> hs = new HashSet<C>();
}

public class C {
    private String sameString;

    public void setSameString(String s){
          this.sameString = s;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. `Vector` is thread-safe so when a thread calls over it, for instance, the `get(int index)`method Is this thread the only owner of`HashSet`**hs**?
2. If a thread call `get(int index)` over **v** and it obtains one **B** object. Then this thread obtains a **C** object and invoke `setSameString(String s)` method, is this write thread-safe? Or mechanism such as `Lock` are needed?

Comment: Thread-safe under what circumstances?  What other threads are there and what might they be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, take a look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) on reasons *not* to use `Vector`. That being said:

1) `Vector` locks on every operation. That means it only allows one thread at a time to call any of its operations (get,set,add,etc.). There is nothing preventing multiple threads from modifying `B`s or their members because they can obtain a reference to them at different times. The only guarantee with `Vector` (or classes that have similar synchronization policies) is that no two threads can concurrently modify the vector and thus get into a race condition (which could throw `ConcurrentModificationException` and/or lead to undefined behavior);

2) As above, there is nothing preventing multiple threads to access `C`s at the same time because they can obtain a reference to them at different times.

If you need to protect the state of an object, you need to do it as close to the state as possible. Java has no concept of a thread *owning* an object. So in your case, if you want to prevent many threads from calling `setSameString` concurrently, you need to declare the method `synchronized`.

I recommend the excellent [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) by Brian Goetz on concurrency for more on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

In case 2. It's not thread-safe because multiple threads could visit the data at the same time. Consider using read-write lock if you want to achieve better performance. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html#readLock()